# View cache clear on node create

Tags: views, blocks, caching

I've searched a lot of this but all kind of cache issues appear not related to this. If this has already been asked I apologize.

I just want to know if this is an embedded feature or a module is needed for this.

My homepage has 12 VIEW blocks with very complex queries so you could imagine that non caching them is not an option.

Some of the views retrieve the latest nodes so my question is: when a user creates a new node, is there a way to clear the block cache on new nodes? If I cache the block for an hour, the rest of the users won't see the new node until an hour passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The combination of [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module and [Cache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions) module should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could done this without contrib modules.

```
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'something') {
    //clear particular views cache here
    cache_clear_all('MY_VIEW_NAME', 'cache_views_data', TRUE);
   }
}
```